# Redirect to external URL using BeforeEnterObserver

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to redirect to a external page using the BeforeEnterObserver interface

this is my code

```
@Route(value = "hello", layout = MainView.class)
@PageTitle("Shortener")
@CssImport("./styles/views/helloworld/hello-world-view.css")
@RouteAlias(value = "", layout = MainView.class)
public class HelloWorldView extends Div implements BeforeEnterObserver{

    private TextField name;
    private H1 mainTitle;
    private String parameter = "";

    public HelloWorldView() {
        setId("hello-world-view");
        
        //some code here
        
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        
        getUI().get().getPage()
               .executeJavaScript("window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/'");
        
    }


}
```

And i getting this error message

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141) ~[na:na]
at com.example.application.views.helloworld.HelloWorldView.beforeEnter(HelloWorldView.java:70) ~[classes/:na]
at com.vaadin.flow.router.internal.AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.sendBeforeEnterEvent(AbstractNavigationStateRenderer.java:606) ~[flow-server-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
```

Seems getUI method return a null object, is there a way to redirect to external website without use getUI method?

Comment: `Seems getUI method return a null object`, that would throw a NPE. Is there anything more interesting in the stack trace ? `beforeEnter(HelloWorldView.java:70)` what line is this ?

Comment: Have you tried `event.getUI()` instead?

Comment: thanks @cfrick ,  i  have used event.getUI() method and it worked

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned cfric, i used event.getUI() and it worked as expected

```
@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    
    //event.forwardTo("https://www.youtube.com");
    //urlurlevent.rerouteTo("about");
    event.getUI().getPage().setLocation("https://www.google.com/");
    
}
```

Comment: Actually you do not need JavaScript call for this as Page has API for setting location, i..e. getPage().setLocation(..)